# Dropbox "sign in" problem

Tags: dropbox

I have had a lot of problems installing Dropbox on elementary OS.

I finally did it, but now I can't log in to Dropbox. When I click the "Sign In" button, nothing happens. However, the "Preferences" button is working.

How can I get Dropbox to properly work on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Nautilus Dropbox which works just fine

```
sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox
dropbox autostart y
dropbox start
```

perhaps u have proxy enabled?

Comment: Thank you. How can I check proxies?

Comment: currently I'm not near my ElmOs but take a look at "preferences" it should be there. Also you have a proxy config inside you global network settings, take a look there to see if you are using a config that allows internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the dropbox implementation from this github: https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox. It integrates into the wingpanel with a matching white icon and appears to work flawlessly for me. I hate using that phrase, but literally my only problem has been that the icon does not change to black with the theme on wallpaper change, but it works.

If this does not solve the issue, it may be related to the browser - I have found that Dropbox now wants you to login using a browser window instead of authenticating through the application itself.

Hope this helps at least a little,

William

Answer (score 0):

You can **disable your proxy** by the following:

1. ->System Settings
2. ->Network
3. -> Proxy (at the end of the list)

Also, it seems that I can't open the link.